# ROS - rosbag playback speed

Tags: ros, opencv-solvepnp

If I change the speed of rosbag, for example speed it up by 10 times, will the PnP algorithm be affected by this, or will I get the same results but with 10 times faster speed ?

I don't need to analyze every frame in rosbag, I'm only interested in the final results.

For example from -r 1:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="--clock -r 1 -k /home/test.bag" />
```

to -r 10:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="--clock -r 10 -k /home/test.bag" />
```

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by PnP algorithm. Totally dependent on what algorithm you're using.

Comment: PnP - Perspective-n-Point. For example: solvepnp from the opencv library

Comment: It still depends on the specific PnP implementation. As for solvepnp from OpenCV, it should work fine.

Comment: @BTables I have tested it, it is not working same!